# Convert SQL to LINQ To Entities

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How can I convert the following SQL from [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3apszkgIh197sJ%3awww.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/%20sql%20group%20by%20row%20with%20max%20value&cd=3&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru&source=www.google.ru) article:

```
select type, variety, price
from fruits
where price = (select min(price) from fruits as f where f.type = fruits.type)
```

I tried it this way:

```
ctx.Fruits.
Where(f => f.Price == ctx.CreateObjectSet<Fruit>().
Where(f1 => f1.Type == f.Type).Min(f1 => f1.Price));
```

but it doesn't work because ctx.CreateObjectSet can not be translated to SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just

```
ctx.Fruits.
Where(f => f.Price == ctx.Fruits.
Where(f1 => f1.Type == f.Type).Min(f1 => f1.Price));
```

Comment: Shame on me! You are right. I just used this CreateObjectSet<T> syntax for joins and didn't get it won't work here

Answer (score 1):

Michael Sagalovich's answer is the correct one for the SQL given, but be aware that if multiple fruits of the same type have the same minimum price, you'll get multiple entries for that type.

This may be more what you're going for: Grabbing only a single smallest-priced fruit for each type:

```
ctx.Fruits.GroupBy(f => f.Type)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(f => f.Price).FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: That's what I started from... but unfortunately my EF provider (MySQL .NET Connector) doesn't support this kind of queries.

Answer (score 1):

Might be clearer and easier if you express it as orderby price, group by fruit.type and then just 'pick' the first fruit in each group.  And since GroupBy preserves order you can do the sort first (or second) depending on which is easier to read (or based on performance if that matters).